# What is ZeroMQ underlying design architecture

Tags: networking, overlay, zeromq, squid

I am comparatively new to ZeroMQ and would like some suggestions regarding its it's internal architecture.

I am planning to use ZeroMQ as a messaging framework for my work. The basic idea what I want to achieve is to be able to dynamically scale the infrastructure based on the load and computational capacity required to achieve a particular workflow deadlines.

So,if if there is a necessity to add more nodes, then the application spawns new nodes and the messaging framework should be able to incorporate the changes as well. I should also be able to be point where the additional computations should occur or how the framework dynamically adds the new nodes (if any). The event on a particular node decides subsequent actions to be performed on other nodes. Here is my scenario or my stack that I am thinking off, but wanted to know if it makes sense:

- User applications
- ZeroMQ messaging
- Squid-Content based routing
- Overlay
- Physical Substrate

I am bit skeptical about the above stack as I believe ZeroMQ helps one to achieve most of the functionality and therby thereby making it simpler.

Few points about my stack:

Physical substrate are the total number of nodes that are available for the computations or as data sources.

Overlay is a logical network that is built dynamically upon the physical network based upon the closest nodes available for a particular workflow. i.e. if two nodes exchange data frequently, then those two nodes are placed logically close to one another. Is a separate overlay like CHORD etc required when we use ZeroMQ?

Squid is basically used for content based routing. Is Squid required when we use ZeroMQ?

ZeroMQ messaging is for the communication between different nodes for an application.

Basically, what I wanted to know is whether above stack can be made simpler given that ZeroMQ has richer functionalities. If so, can someone point or share the thoughts. I am however going through the documentations of ZeroMQ, I am finding it a bit difficult to understand the intrinsic design of ZeroMQ. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's so much specific to your use-case here that it's almost impossible to give any definite answers. ZeroMQ is not a direct replacement for the concepts you've built into your architecture, however it may meet the goals you're trying to meet depending on how you're using them.

My suggestion would be to put your current architecture aside and start trying to build up a new one with ZMQ as its core, and see where you run into limitations that are solved by the other parts of your stack.

As for the "intrinsic design" of ZMQ, here's the basics that you need to understand as a starting point:

1. A ZMQ socket handles connection details for you, including managing network hiccups - but this has limits that you'll need to know
2. There are different kinds of ZMQ sockets, and they have opinions about how you use them.  Some of them communicate asynchronously, some of them are strictly synchronous, some are one way, some are bi-directional.
3. If a connection between two sockets is severed (e.g. one node goes down, there is a network failure - something more than a momentary hiccup), it's your job to recognize that and re-establish that connection
4. There is no built in brokering or topology, you have to design and build that all yourself.

... ultimately, ZMQ provides a toolset for you to build a messaging framework, it does *not* provide a fully realized messaging framework out of the box.  So, yes, it has the power to replace some of the other tools you're currently using, but you'll have to build it.

Comment: I still didn't get the answers to initial questions.When you tell ZMQ has power to replace some of the other tools, what tools are you referring to ? Can you just elaborate the functions that ZMQ could provide or the tools it would eliminate taking my scenario.

Comment: You don't provide specifics on how you're using squid, or how your overlay functions and what problems you're trying to solve and how.  It's conceivable that you're using these things to solve certain problems that ZMQ would give you a simpler way to solve, but impossible for me to know without you going into far more detail on your stack.